# How to process uploaded file with PHP/jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter, upload

I have a import file page that has a form with a file input element in it, when the user clicks submit, it sends the file, with a JSON document, to a url which uses PHP to read the file and processes it, then inserts the data into a MySQL database.

My question is, what is the best way to go about handling this import feature on the import page(the user-facing interface)?  The technologies I am able to use are, Javascript with jQuery for the import file page, and PHP with Codeigniter for the api for serverside processing.

So far, I read people recommending work arounds using iframes, or HTML5 File Api.  Is there a better/safer/easier way to go about creating the file upload feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for usability, for latest browsers i would advice is to use drag & drop upload functionality (that's really cool!) with "old-fashioned" ajax file transfer fallback for old browsers, that is based on flash.

Look at this jQuery plugin for example:
http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

As for security, i would advice to check file mime type if it is possible (if you have PHP fileinfo extension) with PHP. Unfortunately, i am not familiar with Codeigniter (i use ZF), but i am sure that Codeigniter has filters/validators for files.

Form validation in CI:

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/74624/#898858

http://keighl.com/post/codeigniter-file-upload-validation

Comment: I didn't go with any of the links you provided, but I did go with drag and drop ajax.  I used this code for most of references.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/